# Can i get amplify datastore to return related items in a query?

Tags: aws-amplify, datastore

I'm trying to get the related/child items with a datastore query. I have no problems getting them with the graphql API, but it returns a bunch of deleted items which i am unable to filter server side (and keep pagination working nicely).

I'm using react/next/javascript.

``
I have the following models in my schema:

```
type TestResultData @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}, {allow: owner, operations: [create, read, update]}, {allow: groups, groups: ["admin"], operations: [read, create, update, delete]}]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  value: String
  unit: String
  testresultsID: ID! @index(name: "byTestResults")
  TestResultAnalyses: [TestResultAnalysis] @hasMany(indexName: "byTestResultData", fields: ["id"])
  tests: [Test] @manyToMany(relationName: "TestTestResultData")
}
```

and

```
type TestResults @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}, {allow: owner, operations: [create, read, update]}, {allow: groups, groups: ["admin"], operations: [read, create, update, delete]}]) {
  id: ID!
  CustomerID: ID! @index(name: "byCustomer")
  lab: String
  fasting: Boolean
  dateReported: AWSDateTime
  dateCollected: AWSDateTime
  dateTested: AWSDateTime
  type: [TestType]
  note: String
  UploadedFiles: [UploadedFiles] @hasMany(indexName: "byTestResults", fields: ["id"])
  TestResultData: [TestResultData] @hasMany(indexName: "byTestResults", fields: ["id"])
}
```

and I would like to query my TestResults model and have it return the nested TestResultData. However, datastore does not seem to return the related items. (if i do the query using the graphql api it works perfectly, except it contains all my deleted items, which i cannot filter)

this command gets me the TestResults without child items

```
      const data = await DataStore.query(TestResults);
```

I've also tried "querying relations" as per:

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/relational/q/platform/js/#updated-schema

but it doesn't work. I've also upgraded to the latest version of amplify.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this package
https://github.com/sapientpro/nestjs-graphql-eager-load.

This package provides support for eager loading of relations in GraphQL queries, allowing you to significantly reduce the number of database queries required to fetch related data. With this package, you can easily define which relations should be eagerly-loaded for each GraphQL resolver, and the package takes care of the rest.